# Linking AWS Amplify to Apollo Client

Tags: aws-amplify, apollo-client, react-typescript

I am new to Apollo and Graph QL. I have my auth and DB setup with AWS Amplify for a React Native Typescript app.

I want to use Apollo instead of Redux as I have read that is easier and better than Redux obviously this is a personal preference. I want to link my AWS to the Apollo Client.

Can you help me with what URI: to link here so it will get the logged in user information? To store it locally.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cixmkt2ul01o01902vlq3jvrj',
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add url and x-api-key from  AWS amplify configure method